# Read time/date variable from .txt file using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to read a time / date variable from a `.txt` file using an apple script.
Depending on the time / date in the file I want to stop the apple script or run the rest of the apple script.

So the `.txt` file lives on my desktop so my apple script is as below:

```
set desktop_folder to "$HOME/Desktop"
set myFile to "timeDate.txt"
do shell script "echo my file contents is:" & myFile
if myFile < 2021-09-25 then
    error number -128
end if
```

The date in `timeDate.txt` file is less `2021-09-25` so it should stop the rest of the code from running. I can't see why the code doesn't stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare string dates without localization issues for a specific user, they should first be converted to **date objects**:

```
-- script: example for comparing string dates
-- assuming the content of text file is a single entry,
-- in the same format as e.g. "2021-09-25"

set comparedDateString to "2021-09-25"
set readDateString to read (choose file of type "txt")

set dateObject to (current date)
set dateObject's year to (text 1 thru 4 of comparedDateString) as integer
set dateObject's day to (text 9 thru 10 of comparedDateString) as integer
set dateObject's month to (text 6 thru 7 of comparedDateString) as integer
set comparedDate to dateObject

set dateObject's year to (text 1 thru 4 of readDateString) as integer
set dateObject's day to (text 9 thru 10 of readDateString) as integer
set dateObject's month to (text 6 thru 7 of readDateString) as integer
set readDate to dateObject

if readDate < comparedDate then error number -128
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the *content* of **timeDate.txt** is a single entry in the same format as e.g. `2021-09-25` without a trailing *linefeed*, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* does what you are attempting to do.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set myFile to POSIX path of ¬
    (path to desktop) & "timeDate.txt"

set dateString to read myFile

if dateString < "2021-09-25" then return
```

If you run into a issue comparing a `date` as *text/string*, then use:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set thisDate to "2021-09-25"

set myFile to POSIX path of ¬
    (path to desktop) & "timeDate.txt"

set dateString to read myFile

if date dateString < date thisDate then return
```

Comment: Side note: `as string` is redundant. You can get a POSIX path directly from an alias.

Comment: @vadian, Yes, I actually know that and it was left over from when testing with just an _alias_ and concatenating `"timeDate.txt"` without covering to a POSIX path.